# Grub makes 18.04 the default even though I have 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have a system with 18.04 on /dev/sda3 and 20.04 on /dev/sdb6.  grub-mkconfig generates a grub.cfg script that has 18.04 as the default rather than 20.04.  I thought grub-mkconfig was supposed to favor the highest revision rather than the first one it finds. I know I can hardwire the default menu entry in /etc/default/grub, but is there a way to get grub-mkconfig to put 20.04 as the top menu entry

Comment: As far I know it depends on from which system is the leading grub. but I have only experience with systems in bios mode.

Comment: The update-grub only updates menu of current install. Boot into 20.04 and run `sudo grub-install`. If in 18.04 or live installer, you have to chroot into 20.04 to do the grub-install. You also can add a boot stanza to 40_custom in 18.04 but then save as 06_custom. That moves it first in grub menu. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen & http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2076205 (long thread, start at end for latest info on grub menus.

Answer (score 1):

In the folder `/etc/grub.d` you will find some files like `10_linux_proxy` and `30_os-prober_proxy` for example ( and much more ). See screenshot.[image] If both systems are mentioned in `10_linux_proxy`, you should put your 20.04 distro above the 18.04. See screenshot. 
[image]In this screenshot you will see `mint` is mentioned above `windows`, so this file will prioratize `mint`. In my case, as a whole Grub will mention Kubuntu first, then the advanced options for Kubuntu ( in 10_linux_proxy ), Mint, then the advanced options for Mint and then Windows ( in 30_os-prober_proxy ) and then the .iso's I have in my root partition ( 40_custom_proxy ).
 If your 20.04 is mentioned in `30_os-prober_proxy` it will have less priority ( 30 is larger then 10 ) and it will boot to the system mentioned in `10_linux_proxy`. You can copy the entries to your `10_linux_proxy`. 
These actions you have to do as administrator.
Remember to make backups first!!
After you have edited the files do a grub-update. If this does not make sense to you, edit your question and put in the contents of the files mentioning both systems ( as code ). I can then help you in a more specific way.